# Views: Display the value of multiple value field as a separate column/field?

Tags: 7, views

I have a multi value select list field in the content type.

In views it is currently displaying as:

```
title: test title
field_name: value1, value2, value3
```

And I want it to display it like this:

```
title: test title
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3
```

Where field_name is the multi value field.
Any Idea?

Comment: I have not try but i think create tpl file for the views and print the field.

Answer (score 2):

In order to display the value of a field differently.

In the view, click on that particular field listed under FIELDS section. In the window that is opened select **MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS** then from there change ***DISPLAY TYPE*** to one of existing or ***Simple Seperator*** and provide *** html break line br *** as value of Simple Seperator.

Alternative approach:

Under FORMAT -> SHOW select ***Content not Fields*** and choose the View Mode as ***Full Content*** then by default, all the values are displayed one per column.

If you want further editing then consider reading about

1. Delta
2. Module to allow adding PHP Code so you can iterate through values
3. Override a template
4. Preprocess function for that particular field.

Comment: right!! this is what I was trying to suggest

Comment: @harshal this is the most easy and straight-forward method

Answer (score 0):

For Multi value field there is an option in the views field settings 
like given below

Ordered List
Unordered List
Seperated 
...
so you can I guess achieve it using inbuilt views functionality